# Context Menu Like Windows 7

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, contextmenu

I am trying to create a context menu just like a windows 7..
where  I can have a lvl of context... sorry I am new to this environment so bear with me.. thanks in advance.

here's my code..

```
 private void menuContext()
    {
        contextMenu = new RadContextMenu();
        RadMenuItem EditView = new RadMenuItem("Edit/View");
        contextMenu.Items.Add(EditView);
        EditView.Click += EditView_Click;

        RadMenuItem Deactivate = new RadMenuItem("Deactivate");
        contextMenu.Items.Add(Deactivate);
        Deactivate.Click += Deactivate_Click;
        RadMenuSeparatorItem separator = new RadMenuSeparatorItem();
        contextMenu.Items.Add(separator);
        RadMenuItem CreatePurchaseOrder = new RadMenuItem("Create Purchase Order");
        contextMenu.Items.Add(CreatePurchaseOrder);
        CreatePurchaseOrder.Click += CreatePurchaseOrder_Click;
        RadMenuItem CreateItemReceipt = new RadMenuItem("Create Item Receipt");
        contextMenu.Items.Add(CreateItemReceipt);
        CreateItemReceipt.Click += CreateItemReceipt_Click;
        RadMenuItem CreateWithdrawal = new RadMenuItem("Create Withdrawal");
        contextMenu.Items.Add(CreateWithdrawal);
        CreateWithdrawal.Click += CreateWithdrawal_Click;
        RadMenuItem CreateStockTransfer = new RadMenuItem("Create Stock Transfer");
        contextMenu.Items.Add(CreateStockTransfer);
        CreateStockTransfer.Click += CreateStockTransfer_Click;
        RadMenuItem CreateStockAdjustment = new RadMenuItem("Create Stock Adjustment");
        contextMenu.Items.Add(CreateStockAdjustment);
        CreateStockAdjustment.Click += CreateStockAdjustment_Click;
        RadMenuItem CreateStockConversion = new RadMenuItem("Create Stock Conversion");
        contextMenu.Items.Add(CreateStockConversion);
        CreateStockConversion.Click += CreateStockConversion_Click;
    }
```

here's a picture... what I want is to have something like a lvl of menu.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a new item and add it to the already created one. Here's a short version of your context menu with some child items.

```
RadMenuItem EditView = new RadMenuItem("Edit/View");
RadMenuItem Child1 = new RadMenuItem("Child1");
RadMenuItem Child2 = new RadMenuItem("Child2");

EditView.Items.Add(Child1);
EditView.Items.Add(Child2);

contextMenu.Items.Add(EditView);
```